# How dow I stringify an array without spaces between its elements?

Tags: arrays, powershell, string-conversion

```
$readFile = get-content $readInput

#create an empty array to be filled with bank account numbers
$fNameArray = @()

for($i = 0; $i -lt $readFile.length; $i++){

    #assigns a random letter from the list to $letter.
    #$letter = get-random -inputobject ("A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z") -count $readFile.length 
    $letter = $readFile[$i] | foreach-object{get-random -inputobject ("A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z") -count $readFile[$i].length}

    $fnameArray += "$letter"
}
$fnameArray
```

the code is reading in a file that has a list of names and randomizing the letters for Data Masking. The only problem I am running into is the output is like such:

```
L R Y E B
R O M I
U Q N G R
H K Y
M G A W Q
J G W Y D K T
X E Q
J Y P I G
```

It looks like it is output with spaces between the letters. How do I eliminate them?

Comment: Simplest way would be to make `$fnameArray` into a string instead of an array.

Comment: `P S A N FV Q S NA P S H MF R GV J E M IB T Y R S Z ME A FK H X T S` This is the output of `$fNameArray = ""`

Comment: @Eris: That won't help, because it is the stringification of array `$letter` as `"$letter"` that introduces the spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The unary form of the `-join` operator joins (concatenates) all array elements without a separator.

```
> -join ('a', 'b', 'c')
abc
```

Therefore, simply use:

```
$fnameArray += -join $letter
```

---

By contrast, `"$letter"` stringifies the array using `$OFS` (the output field separator) as the separator, which defaults to a *space*, which explains your output.

Therefore, you could alternatively set `$OFS` to `''` (the empty string) and use `"$letter"`.
However, the `-join` approach is simpler and doesn't require you to create a local scope for / restore the previous `$OFS` value.